# Install python in a windows web hosting running IIS 7

Tags: windows, iis, python

How do I install python in a web host running IIS 7? Mostly of my research suggest to go to the Internet Service Manager but I can only access the server through a web browser. Is this possible? What I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some kind of console access in order to do this. If it's not your web server then you'll need to request it from the administrator but I wouldn't hold your breathe.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Is that the only way to do it?

Comment: I'd expect so, yes.